# Push notification of mac OSX when is force quit

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to get a callback when a push notification is received but the mac app is force killed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, first you have to confirm that UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate inside AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    //here you have to put these line of code to confirm relevant delegate and to enable device for remote notification if device is still not given access for it
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    return true
}
```

after that you have to you have to add following two separate method to handle push notification.

if your device iOS version is below than 10.0 then use this method..

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    //To print notification payload
    print(userInfo)

}
```

otherwise you can use this method to handle push notification..

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


//To print notification payload:
print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

}
```

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification doesn't get called if mac app isn't running